# Show only games that the "Golfos" team has won

Tags: xpath

I would like to know how to ask an XPATH query to solve the question: It shows the games that the "Golfos" team has won.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<juego>
<ronda num="1">
<equipo nombre="golfos" puntuacion="22">
</equipo>
<equipo nombre="rios" puntuacion="12">
</equipo>
</ronda>
<ronda num="2">
<equipo nombre="golfos" puntuacion="2">
</equipo>
<equipo nombre="rios" puntuacion="26">
</equipo>
</ronda><ronda num="3">
<equipo nombre="ricos" puntuacion="44">
</equipo>
<equipo nombre="golfos" puntuacion="46">
</equipo>
</ronda>
</juego>
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: OUTPUT:
<ronda num="1"><golfos><rios></ronda>

<ronda num="3"><golfos><rios></ronda>

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use :

```
//ronda/equipo[@nombre="golfos"][@puntuacion>preceding-sibling::equipo/@puntuacion or @puntuacion>following-sibling::equipo/@puntuacion]
```

We look for "ronda" nodes where the team Golfos scores more points than the preceding or following team in the same node.

Output : 2